# Change value of PHP Array without using the keys

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am stuck modifying a value in a PHP array.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

[image]

I have to change this value  :

[image]

I dont have to use to the keys : 900 and 2200 cause the values can change...
How can I process to replace the first value "1578" by another in my $data array ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: do you have to replace the first value "1578" in just [900] or also in  the first value "1578" in [1250], [1500], [1750]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to change the first value of 900 without using 900 as a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested loop.

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
  foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
    if( $k === 0 ) {
        $data[$key][$k] = 'some value here';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would change everytime the first value of your array or just the first "1578" of your array ?

If is the first case you can do : `$data[900][array_key_first($data[900])] = $newValue;`

Else you can search the key of the first 1578 and change it :

```
$key = array_search('1578', $data[900]);
$data[900][$key] = $newValue;
```

And if you want to change all the first 1578 in all your sub-array, loop on it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I said I need to change the first value of 900 but I cant use 900 as a key. by the way 1578 is not always the same value as well it can change too. I dont know if Im clear or not^^

Answer (score 0):

make a loop on your array like:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $arr)
{
    $firstKey = array_search(1578, $arr);
    # replace
    if ($firstKey !== false)
        $data[$key][$firstKey] = "my new value";
}
```

Comment: thanks, it might work but in my case I forgot to specify that 1578 is not a fixed value. it can change from one array to another

Comment: do you have a map like if the key is 900 then the value is 1578, etc... then use this map

Answer (score 0):

You can use double foreach loop and than break immediately after you find the first value like this:

```
foreach($data as $key1 => $value1){
    foreach($data[$key1] as $key2 => $value2){
        $data[$key1][$key2] = $your_new_value;
        break 2;
    }
}
```

The 2 after the break statement means that you break out of both loops at the same time. Alternatively you can use array_keys which returns the keys of an array like this.

```
$key1 = array_keys($data)[0];
$key2 = array_keys($data[$key1])[0];
$data[$key1][$key2] = $your_new_value;
```

array_keys returns an array so the [0] at the end of the line means the first element of that array, because the first element of that array is usually the first key.